# Checkbox check first time not working, after second time, it is OK

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox with label. When user click the label, it will check if checkbox checked. The first time, I click the label, the box is checked, but no alert action. After I click the second time, it start to function, alert action happen. What did I do wrong. I have tried to use individual ID. Click not working either.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var elements = { "emo_lol": "1", "emo_cool": "2", "emo_cute": "3" };
   
  jQuery.each( elements, function( id_name, num ) {

    $('#'+ id_name).click(function(){
    
       if ($('#'+id_name +'_checkbox').prop('checked')) {
             alert('Checked');
         }else{
           alert('unchecked');
           }
       });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox" id="emo_lol_checkbox">
<label id="emo_lol" for="emo_lol_checkbox" >LOL !</label>
       
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cool_checkbox">
<label id="emo_cool" for="emo_cool_checkbox" >COOL !</label>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cute_checkbox"> 
<label id="emo_cute" for="emo_cute_checkbox" >CUTE !</label>
```

Comment: Posted the Answer below, see if it helps you.

Comment: Try to use jsFiddle... It will always help us...

Comment: Your code is producing alert [here](http://jsfiddle.net/33jdskq2/1/). looks like you missed jquery.js file in your environment and you missed it in snippet . And don't use script tag when you are writing code in JS panel .

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Did you find solution in some answer here? So please accept the answer... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('label').click(function() {
        if ($('#'+ $(this).attr('id') + '_checkbox').prop('checked') === false) {
            alert('Checked');
        }
        else {
            alert('Unchecked');
        }
    });
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox" id="emo_lol_checkbox">
<label id="emo_lol" for="emo_lol_checkbox" >LOL !</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cool_checkbox">
<label id="emo_cool" for="emo_cool_checkbox" >COOL !</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cute_checkbox"> 
<label id="emo_cute" for="emo_cute_checkbox" >CUTE !</label>
```

Also be sure, you have included jQuery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in new version of jQuery you can use insted of this:

```
if ($('#'+ $(this).attr('id') + '_checkbox').prop('checked') === false) {
    alert('Checked');
}
else {
    alert('Unchecked');
}
```

This piece of code:

```
// Just be careful, its inverted. Because, when you click label to check checkbox, the checkbox is still unchecked, and after alert will be checked...
if ($('#'+ $(this).attr('id') + '_checkbox').is(':checked') {
    alert('Unchecked');
}
else {
    alert('Checked');
}
```

[Workind DEMO here in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/ycqq9u11/)

Comment: sorry, I just forgot to paste the });, the issue, it doesn't alert when I click the label first time, second time it will alert

Comment: "Just be careful, its inverted. Because, when you click label to check checkbox, the checkbox is still unchecked, and after alert will be checked..." - this solved my otherwise unrelated problem - thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify things, you don't need each loop:

```
 $('label').click(function() {
        name=this.id;
       if ($('#'+name+'_checkbox').prop('checked')) {
         alert('Checked');
       }
       else{
         alert('unchecked');
       }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fqvajvo1/2/

Script running correctly, script checks  prop, but on label click -> checkbox is really unchecked, property changing comes later.

So, maybe in your case reverse logic could help (if you need alerts at all):

http://jsfiddle.net/fqvajvo1/4/ :)

Comment: This is correct; but has one bug... Its inverted... Because, when you click `label` to check checkbox, the `checkbox` is still unchecked, and after alert will be checked...

Comment: Yes, noticed it, too - not sure what is intention with alerts, but yes... some reverse logic is needed here, def...:) http://jsfiddle.net/fqvajvo1/4/

Answer (score 0):

I always use `.is(':checked')`.I find it way more reliable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var elements = { "emo_lol": "1", "emo_cool": "2", "emo_cute": "3" };

      jQuery.each( elements, function( id_name, num ) {

        $('#'+id_name +'_checkbox').change(function(){

           if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               alert('Checked');
           }else{
               alert('unchecked');
           }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: This is correct; but has one bug... Its inverted... Because, when you click `label` to check checkbox, the `checkbox` is still unchecked, and after alert will be checked...

Comment: Just switch click to change

Comment: Switching `click` to `change` will totally break the functionality... Because `label` has no `change` method... You are performing `click` method on a `label` and changed is `checkbox` associated with it...

Comment: No, it will not, as long as you bind the change function on the checkbox. When clicking the label it will trigger the change event on the checkbox

Answer (score -1):

your click id is not complete name,so add complete name and call $(this) property will be ok...

```js
 var elements = { "emo_lol": "1", "emo_cool": "2", "emo_cute": "3" };
   
  jQuery.each( elements, function( id_name, num ) {
      
    $('#'+ id_name+'_checkbox').click(function(){
    
       if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
             alert('Checked');
         }else{
           alert('unchecked');
           }
       });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox" id="emo_lol_checkbox">
<label id="emo_lol" for="emo_lol_checkbox" >LOL !</label>
       
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cool_checkbox">
<label id="emo_cool" for="emo_cool_checkbox" >COOL !</label>
    
<input type="checkbox" name="emo_checkbox"  id="emo_cute_checkbox"> 
<label id="emo_cute" for="emo_cute_checkbox" >CUTE !</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use .on to work for all events and all clicks [on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Mainly used for dynamic creating elements

```
$(document).on('click','selector',function(){

});
```

Use class names for best options for grouped elements